# PHP email formatted content

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am creating an email form for my website which will allow a user to create an email and appear to be sent from any email address they wish. i.e. davidcameron@downingstreet.com.

The form works fine, until I made one small change. I previously allowed the user to submit the content of the email but was finding difficulty in formatting the content (i.e. making areas bold, using a table etc).

(Form code now)

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="send.php">

<p>To: <input type="text" name="to" /></p>
<p>From-Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>From-Email: <input type="text" name="from" /></p>
<p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /></p>


<input type="submit" value="Send E-Mail" ></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So I thought it would be easier to submit the content myself in my 'send.php' code that actually sends the email message. This is displayed below:

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $to =$_REQUEST['to'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $name =$_REQUEST['name'];
    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $content = ?><font face="arial"><b>Your question has been received/b>

    Your booking has been confirmed with the supplier.
    Please visit the <a href="questionstory.co.uk"> Question Portal</a> for more information.

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Question subject</td>
    <td> Room</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Traveller</td>
    <td>Maria Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Requester</td>
    <td>Tony Smith</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <br/>


     </font>

    <?
    $header="From: $from"."<$sender_email>\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$content,$header);
    echo 'sent successfully';

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, when I click submit, my server finds an error. I can only presume it is because of my HTML element as this error was not occurring previously without it.

Can anyone advise how I can fix this / if you can suggest an easier way for me to format the email content I would like?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set your content value to

`$content = ''`

Since your $content is undefined that is why you are getting error.

Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $content =
        '<span style="font-family: arial"><b>Your question has been received</b>
            <br>
            Your booking has been confirmed with the supplier.
            Please visit the <a href="questionstory.co.uk"> Question Portal</a> for more information.

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Question subject</td>
                    <td> Room</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Traveller</td>
                    <td>Maria Smith</td>
                </tr>
                <td>Requester</td>
                <td>Tony Smith</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br/>
            </span>';

    $header = "From:".$from;
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$content,$header);
    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'sent successfully';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed';
    }


?>
```

> Note: `<font>` tag **not supported in HTML5**

**EDIT 01**

Include this lines too

```
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$header .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1';
```

Comment: Firstly many thanks for your response. I implemented this code however when I received the email through, it showed all html tags. Any thoughts how to avoid this and for it to implement the formatting required? Many thanks

Comment: I added the lines suggested just below $from, have run the code and found same problem still.

Comment: should place below `$header = "From:".$from;` and whats the error??

Comment: moved to where suggested, still coming through in the email showing all of this everything from <span>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85301/discussion-between-user289040-and-abdulla).